# Which processor can I put in a Dell Optiplex 210L?

Tags: cpu, dell-optiplex

What kind of different processor can I put in a Dell Optiplex 210L?

I know there is an Intel Celeron 2.8GHz in it now, but the thing is slow as hell. I don't have much on my computer, but I use internet a lot (it's not my internet connection thats slow).

When I press `Ctrl+Alt+Del` I see my computer uses 100% CPU every second. That is why I want to put a different processor in my computer.

Anyone have an idea of which I can try?

Comment: That has nothing to do with what processor you have - something is obviously acting up - what process specifically is using 100%?

Comment: Sounds like malware to me....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 2):

That model should be able to use any Intel Pentium 4 processor.

Comment: Not a program that is 100% all the time its the cpu it self. When I look in the performance tab in the task list its full on 100% and occasionally it jumps to 50%. Or is it something else?

Comment: @Wim - If you CPU is at 100% load it means you have a process or processes running.  Before you attempt to purchase unsupported hardware ( by Intel ) that you might or might not have to pay a premium I would simply format your computer.

Comment: Or boot from a live CD. If that is fast then you know your current installation on the HDD has problem, and not the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

According to Intel, all/most of these should work in 915G-based boards, some of the later ones may require a BIOS upgrade to work so [YMMV](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YMMV), depending on Dell:

```
 - Processor Family     Processor Number        Processor Speed         Bus Frequency           L2 Cache Size       
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    660                     3.60 GHz                800 MHz                 2 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    650                     3.40 GHz                800 MHz                 2 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    640                     3.20 GHz                800 MHz                 2 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    630                     3 GHz                   800 MHz                 2 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    570J                    3.80 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    560J                    3.60 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    560                     3.60 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    551                     3.40 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    550J                    3.40 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    550                     3.40 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    541                     3.20 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    540J                    3.20 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    540                     3.20 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    531                     3 GHz                   800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    530J                    3 GHz                   800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    530                     3 GHz                   800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    524                     3.06 GHz                533 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    521                     2.80 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    520J                    2.80 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    520                     2.80 GHz                800 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    511                     2.80 GHz                533 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    506                     2.66 GHz                533 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    505J                    2.66 GHz                533 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Pentium® 4    505                     2.66 GHz                533 MHz                 1 MB                
 - Intel® Celeron® D    346                     3.06 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    345J                    3.06 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    340J                    2.93 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    336                     2.80 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    335J                    2.80 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    330J                    2.66 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    326                     2.53 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    325J                    2.53 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    320                     2.40 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    315                     2.26 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB              
 - Intel® Celeron® D    310                     2.13 GHz                533 MHz                 256 KB
```

If you are seeing 50-100% CPU usage when you aren't using it heavily, then you have something running out-of-control in the background.

[Check for malware](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533), and perhaps update system drivers.

You can figure out what's busy by using utilities like Windows' [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx), or MS' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).

If you've had the system a long time and you can't identify the source of the mystery CPU usage, it may be time to consider a wipe and reinstall of Windows.